# Adding `post_author` in php

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have following markup to show a shortcode:

```
<div class="my_edit_button">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[something]'); ?>
</div>
```

Then I am trying to make it so that the shortcode is only shown to post author by using the following:

```
return ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID);
```

But I am not sure how to incorporate both into one.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can control if the author is current user and if TRUE print your button. I think something like this can work.

```
<?php if($post->post_author == $current_user->ID): ?>
<div class="my_edit_button">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[something]'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```